# установа mingw для clion

Tags: linux, mingw, clion, archlinux

Я пытаюсь установит `mingw` в `clion` так как слышал, что в нём можно находясь в `linux` компилировать проект под `windows`. Но поле установки `clion` его не видит. Подскажите как правильно его подключить (я использую последнию версию clion на arch linux)